# Apt stopped working in ubuntu 20.04. E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dpkg

I have been facing this problem for a while now. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 the regular desktop version and for some reason, apt has stopped working. Whenever I do `sudo apt install xyz` I get the following error: `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`

So I run the command, and lo and behold my computer freezes. I have tried this multiple times and it still freezes. I have tried many things but it doesn't seem to work. What should I do. After it freezes i wait for 1 hour, 2 hours but I still get no response from the PC. Finally I shut it down by pressing the power button which is not the safest thing to do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you installing a package or upgrading system and interrupted the process at middle stage? What happens after you power off and restart?

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes" ? Does the computer stop working or is the cooomanjust a long time about producing output ? if you run `top` in a other terinal window, does that also stop updating ?

Comment: Soren A it stops nothing can happen the mouse doesn't move nothing happens on the screen at all. Completly freezed.

Comment: Akib Azmain I didn't do anything. One day I was installing a package and suddenly got this error. Restarting doesnt change anything